# Format ASUS external hard drive AN300

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, asus, external-hdd, format

I am trying to format a new external HDD of ASUS (model AN300). Ubuntu recognizes only a "CD ROM" when I plug it to the computer, names ASUS Webstorage. I tried to follow instructions, on [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_6806590_mount-external-hard-drive-linux.html) link.

But when I type `fdisk -l` on my laptop I don't get any line, so I don't know if and where the hdd is mounted.

I also tried [this](http://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=2861.0) .
But nothing work for my hdd, how can we beat the system?

[image]

Comment: if you install/run GParted this is an excellent tool for organising partitions and formatting drives. Downloadable from the Software Centre

Comment: Hi Simon, I've tried to open the device with GParted, but it doesn't even see the hard drive that I plug. When I press devices on GParted is shows only the internal hard drive at /dev/sda

Comment: I'll leave you with @Mitch and his knowledge, as I'm still new here :)

Comment: @Mitch This link http://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=2861.0 seems to suggest there is noway to use this HDD in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Open Disk from Dash, and follow the images below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried to open the hard drive through the disk utility but it doesn't show the hard drive, it just shows a Virtual CDrom in which there is a program of ASUS for Webstorage.

Comment: When you highlight that, what size does it show?

Comment: Hi, I try to put an image here but it says I don't have enough reputations to do that...In any case, it shows MODEL : ASMT Virtual CDROM, and for Device : /dev/sr0

Comment: Upload the image to the web, give me the link, and I'll add it.

Comment: If you boot from LiveCD, do you see the drive?  Is the drive plugged in to a USB2.0 or USB3.0 port?

Comment: This is the link to the image - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-NrJx3VgVijWElxZ3UwMFhyM00/edit?usp=sharing